# Can’t find admin file of sales grid column

Tags: magento, php

I’m trying to take out one of the lines in the ‘Purchased From’ column… have tried to look for hours but cannot find the file which displays that. Each line has    , so you would think it would be easy to find. Anyone who knows which file it is? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the folder which stores all the column render files. The one I specifically wanted for the Purchased From column is the Store.php file, located at /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer. Again, all the columns are stored there, so if you need to change something in the other columns, just look in that folder. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Simple and nondesctructible way:

First, copy `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`. Be sure to make directories if they don’t exist.

Then remove code in it (around 84 row) like

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'     => 'store_id',
        'type'      => 'store',
        'store_view'=> true,
        'display_deleted' => true,
    ));
}
```

Finally, re-login to backend.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I delete one of those lines though... for example, it says in HTML [website name]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[store name]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[store view name]. Let's say I only want to display the [store name]... how would I do that?

Comment: In the copy of file within the function `_prepareColumns` you need to cut any section what begins with `$this->addColumn(` and left what you need